# Spring boot No qualifying bean of type '' available

Tags: java, spring

```
AccessRecord ar =  context.getBean(AccessRecord.class);
```

error:
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.xxx.xxx.xxx.AccessRecord' available

---

I want to instantiate javabean as follows：

```
 @Entity
@Table(name="access_record")
public class AccessRecord {
```

Comment: An Entity is not a bean

Comment: How do I instantiate the "AccessRecord" class?

Comment: With new keyword `new AccessRecord()`

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question ！Other way ？

Answer (score 0):

["5. Cause: Proxied Beans"](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-nosuchbeandefinitionexception)

It help me, when i call bean from context by interface.
You need something like

```
IAccessRecord accessRecord = context.getBean(IAccessRecord.class);
```